# Restlet: retrieve the username of a Digest authenticated user in a ServerResource

Tags: restlet

in my REST server users authenticate using DigestAuthentication. When a user is logged in, he should, for instance, see some entries related to his username.

My problem is that, although users login succesfully, when they access a ServerResource implementation, I don't know what is the username of the user accessing this class.

This is my main

```
public class Main extends Application{

    @Override
    public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        router.attach("/profile", UserResource.class);
        return router;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Component component = new Component();
        component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);

        DigestAuthenticator guard = new DigestAuthenticator(null, testRealm, secretServerKey);

        guard.setWrappedVerifier(new LocalVerifier() {
            @Override
            public char[] getLocalSecret(String arg0) {

                .. return the user's password if it exists.

            }
        });

        guard.setNext(new Main());
        component.getDefaultHost().attach("/protected",guard);

        Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters()
            .add(new JacksonConverter());
        component.start();
    }
}
```

Then, inside the class ServerResource mentioned in the  Main.createInboundRoot(), how can I retrieve the username of the logged user?